# A probability question on number of Balls

Tags: probability

I have below question -

In a box, there are 2 blue and 2 red balls. I need to guess the color of the ball without replacement, I will  receive a dollar if you are correct. What is the dollar amount I should pay.

My answer is as follows -
In 1st draw, my probability of correct answer is `1/2`

In 2nd draw, my probability of correct answer is `2/3`

In 3rd draw, my probability of correct answer is `2/2`

So, expected amount will be - `1/2+2/3+1 = 2.166667`

However the correct answer is given by `2.833333`.

Can you please help where I made mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You nailed the first two draws of (1/2), (2/3).

Then you went off the rails in two ways.

For third draw:

(1/3) chance that 1st 2 draws the same color.  When that
happens, you are certain to be right.

(2/3) chance that 1st 2 draws different colors.  When that happens
you have a (1/2) chance of being right.

Also, you overlooked that on 4th draw, you are certain to be right.

Final answer:

$$(1/2) + (2/3) + \{[(1/3) \times 1] + [(2/3) \times (1/2)\} + (1).$$

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain the statement `(1/3) chance that 1st 2 draws the same color`? Why the probability is `1/3`?

Comment: @Daniel Assume that 1st draw is blue.  Then, just before 2nd draw, there are 2 red and 1 blue to draw from.  chances of the 2nd draw also being blue is therefore (1/3).  Note that the problem is **symmetric** between red and blue.  Therefore, if 1st draw is red, the **analysis is identical.**